# How do I coordinate a SQL Server stored procedure providing pagination with Mulesoft?

Tags: sql-server, pagination, mulesoft

I created a stored procedure where I provide multiple pages back to the caller on execution. In this one case, the caller is from Mulesoft.

Here is the creation code for some sample data and the logic for the stored procedure.

```
CREATE SCHEMA pldScratch

CREATE TABLE pldScratch.SampleFruits 
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) , 
    FruitName VARCHAR(50) , 
    Price INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Apple', 20)
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Apricot', 12)
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Banana', 8)
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Cherry', 11)
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Strawberry', 26)
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Lemon', 4)  
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Kiwi', 14)  
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Coconut', 34) 
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Orange', 24)  
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Raspberry', 13)
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Mango', 9)
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Mandarin', 19)
INSERT INTO pldScratch.SampleFruits VALUES ('Pineapple', 22)
GO

-- examine the newly written data ordered by price
SELECT * 
FROM pldScratch.SampleFruits
ORDER BY price

-- stored procedure logic
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT
DECLARE @RowsOfPage AS INT
DECLARE @MaxTablePage AS decimal(10,2) 
    
SET @PageNumber = 1
SET @RowsOfPage = 4 -- NOTE: I am expecting Mulesoft to send me the desired rows per page,
                  --       for now, I am dubbing the value as 4 with this small sampling.

SELECT @MaxTablePage = COUNT(*) FROM pldScratch.SampleFruits
SET @MaxTablePage = CEILING (@MaxTablePage / @RowsOfPage)

WHILE @MaxTablePage >= @PageNumber
BEGIN
    SELECT FruitName, Price 
    FROM pldScratch.SampleFruits
    ORDER BY Price 
       OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * @RowsOfPage ROWS
       FETCH NEXT @RowsOfPage ROWS ONLY

    SET @PageNumber = @PageNumber + 1
END
```

This pagination routine works, in that I return all the inserted 13 rows back, ordered by price in 4 pages; 3 pages have 4 rows (from the `@RowsOfPage` setting), and 1 page (last page) has a single row. The data appears to be ordered correctly, and the offset seems to work.

My question is: how am I sending this back to MuleSoft? When this executes, the data is paged in a while loop. My thoughts are `@PageNumber`, `@MaxTablePage` as input/output parameters. Does MuleSoft need the OFFSET too?

I have it here as calculated: `(@PageNumber - 1) * @RowsOfPage`. The `@RowsOfPage` will be an incoming parameter to me from the MuleSoft call, the calculated value for OFFSET will change each iteration in the WHILE LOOP.

I haven't worked with MuleSoft, so I am uncertain about what I need to do here to provide all the elements the front-end developer may need back from the stored procedure to page the resultset(s) to the end user. Please advise.

Comment: Protip: don't use a `PROCEDURE` for `SELECT` queries - use a `FUNCTION` or `VIEW`.

Comment: Thanks, Dai. Assuming I do that, what am I sending back to the caller in this function? (I don't think a view would work here).

Comment: I don't know why you have a loop at all - just use a single `SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE x = y ORDER BY sortCriterion OFFSET ( @pageIndex * @pageSize ) ROWS FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS;` - that's all you need.

Comment: It is not "with MuleSoft" or "from/to MuleSoft" since MuleSoft is a company name. You do mean "to/from" a Mule Runtime **application**, ie an application that you develop that is deployed into a Mule Runtime server.

Comment: Thanks for the correction aled. Yes, let's state it that way if that is more helpful. Do we have anyone on here familiar with this product who can answer my base question?

Comment: OK, @Dai, I will try your alternative. The question still remains, does this product, or as aled has said "Mule Runtime application" need the offset value to be able to paginate the data back from the api to the front-end interface? If so, whether in a fetch loop, or not, how do I get the calculated offset value back to the "Mule Runtime application"?

Comment: @Dai, the suggested code, does not page--it brings back all the rows. Try it on your end, if you are willing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone following this thread in the future, the "lingo" of the API developers using the MuleSoft product centered around TOP and SKIP. As for me, a backend developer, I was uncertain whether I needed to provide multiple, pre-paginated data sets packaged back to the calling API, or whether the expectation was to receive incoming parameters from the API, returning only the single data set requested.

It turns out the SCALA/data engineering team prefers the packaged multiple sets, while the MuleSoft product API developers prefer the single data set approach.

With that said, two separate means of access were necessary to provide. The approach I shared initially, provided for the SCALA developers, and this approach needed for the MuleSoft product API developers:

```
  SELECT @MaxTablePage = count(*) FROM #ListOfInvoicesOrLoadOrders
  SET @MaxTablePage = CEILING(@MaxTablePage/@RowsOfPageOrSkip)

     SELECT 
         FruitName,Price
      FROM pldScratch.SampleFruits
      ORDER BY Price
       FROM #ListOfInvoicesOrLoadOrders
      ORDER BY InvoiceDate DESC, CustomerName ASC
      OFFSET (@RowsOfPage * @PageNumber) ROWS 
      FETCH NEXT @RowsOfPage ROWS ONLY
```

The parameters for the stored proc required for this to work are as follows:

```
       @PageNumber int  -- input
       @RowsOfPage int  -- input
       @MaxTablePage decimal(10,2) OUTPUT
```

Now to address the "judgy/preachy" stuff under the comments section.

1. The real stored proc has a lot more going on than the simplistic
   fruit sample I was able to show here, like CTEs and transforms that are not
   really practical in a VIEW or a FUNCTION.
2. There was indeed cause for a loop when packaging up multiple data sets for a
   specific set of developers.
3. After a 40-year career in IT, and being one of the second-wave generation of database
   product developers that made two-phase commits possible in distributed
   environments, never assume because one doesn't phrase a question in the
   EXACT vernacular that you would prefer it be asked, (a) doesn't mean you are
   talking to a moron; (b) nor does it mean a snarky correction about the
   question is answer enough. I can deal with the snark, that
   comes with the territory. What I find fatiguing to deal with is all the snark,
   without having something to be snarky about. If you must correct, then correct--
   but do so with an answer to the question asked, when you don't, those of us who ask(ed) the question will
   assume you don't know the answer. Protip: If that is the case, don't leave a comment
   at all, it doesn't sound as smart as you may think it does.